# How to encrypt decrypt with RSA keys in java

Tags: java, openssl, rsa

I need to replace the encrypt and decrypt step from Unix to java code with the `rsaprivatekey.pem` and `rsapublickey.pem` keys generated with openssl

I generate the keys

```
openssl  genrsa  -out /tmp/rsaprivatekey.pem  -des3 1024
openssl rsa -in /tmp/rsaprivatekey.pem -pubout -out /tmp/rsapublickey.pem
```

i use the keys in unix (i need do it in java)

```
echo "Text to encript"| openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey /tmp/rsapublickey.pem -pubin -out out.enc
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey /tmp/rsaprivatekey.pem -in out.enc
```

This was my attempt to do it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Base64 base64 = new Base64();

    String TextStream = "this is the input text";
    byte[] Cipher;
    System.out.println("input:\n" + TextStream);
    Cipher = encrypt(TextStream);
    System.out.println("cipher:\n" + base64.encodeAsString(Cipher));
    System.out.println("decrypt:\n" + decrypt(Cipher));
}

private static byte[] encrypt(String Buffer) {
    try {

        Cipher rsa;
        rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        rsa.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getPrivateKey(PRIVATE_PATH));
        return rsa.doFinal(Buffer.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


private static String decrypt(byte[] buffer) {
    try {
        Cipher rsa;
        rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        rsa.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getPrivateKey(PUBLIC_PATH));
        byte[] utf8 = rsa.doFinal(buffer);
        return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String filename) throws Exception {
    File f = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
    dis.readFully(keyBytes);
    dis.close();

    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
}

public static PublicKey getPublicKey(String filename) throws Exception {
    File f = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
    dis.readFully(keyBytes);
    dis.close();

    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return kf.generatePublic(spec);
}
```

but it not works, the PKCS8EncodedKeySpec/X509EncodedKeySpec are not correct... but i do not know what to put

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Mind Reader.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/133242)

Comment: ang about I'm getting my crystal ball ready

Comment: Also see [How to encrypt decrypt with RSA keys in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10517930/608639), [Equivalent to OpenSSL commands in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39084741/608639), [How to encrypt decrypt with RSA keys in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10517930/608639), [OpenSSL Encryption of Session Key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23114808/608639)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're having problems reading PEM files.  The JPA doesn't directly support the PEM format.  You have two options, either convert them to DER encoded files (you can use openSSL to do this) or the you can use the bouncy castle API to read (or write) PEM files.  the class you'd be interested in is called PEMReader (and maybe also PEMWriter).  [Here is the Javadoc](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/util/io/pem/PemReader.html) on the bouncycastle website.

Comment: The Javadoc link above is broken, the current links are [here](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/index.html).

Answer (score 13):

Solution:

Thanks to @Sanjeev, using the bouncy castle API, I was able to encrypt/decrypt with the keys generated by openssl

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    KeyPair keyPair = readKeyPair(new File(PRIVATE_PATH), "pass"); 
    // if the private key is not encripted, pass can be anything.
    Key publickey = readPublicKey(new File(PUBLIC_PATH), "pass"); 
    Base64 base64 = new Base64();
    String text = "this is the input text";
    byte[] encripted;
    System.out.println("input:\n" + text);
    encripted = encrypt(keyPair.getPublic(), text);
    System.out.println("cipher:\n" + base64.encodeAsString(encripted));
    System.out.println("decrypt:\n" + decrypt(keyPair.getPrivate(), encripted));        
}

private static byte[] encrypt(Key pubkey, String text) {
    try {
        Cipher rsa;
        rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        rsa.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubkey);
        return rsa.doFinal(text.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


private static String decrypt(Key decryptionKey, byte[] buffer) {
    try {
        Cipher rsa;
        rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        rsa.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, decryptionKey);
        byte[] utf8 = rsa.doFinal(buffer);
        return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private static KeyPair readKeyPair(File privateKey, String keyPassword) throws IOException {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(privateKey);
    PEMReader r = new PEMReader(fileReader, new DefaultPasswordFinder(keyPassword.toCharArray()));
    try {
        return (KeyPair) r.readObject();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        r.close();
        fileReader.close();
    }
}

private static Key readPublicKey(File privateKey, String keyPassword) throws IOException {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(privateKey);
    PEMReader r = new PEMReader(fileReader, new DefaultPasswordFinder(keyPassword.toCharArray()));
    try {
        return (RSAPublicKey) r.readObject();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        r.close();
        fileReader.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be "UTF-8"?

Comment: Hi @caeycae, I am following you post, i also have trouble on this. In which JAR/Library contains DefaultPasswordFinder?

Comment: Did you found a solution for which jar file we have to include for DefaultPasswordFinder?

Comment: private static class DefaultPasswordFinder implements PasswordFinder {
        private final char[] password;

        DefaultPasswordFinder(char[] password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        @Override
        public char[] getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
    }